# Approval Process: What status' indicate the record is Submitted for Approval

Tags: approval-process

I am trying to detect whether a record is currently in an approval process.

This is similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-to-check-if-a-record-is-locked-or-not-in-apex-during-an-approval-process) but a different approach. I want to use the status of the youngest ProcessInstance to determine if the record is currently pending approval.

The list of values for the `ProcessInstance.Status` picklist is below. I am trying to Understand which of these means the record is pending approval.

- Approved
- Rejected
- Recalled
- Fault
- Pending
- Hold
- Reassigned
- Submitted
- NoResponse

I am sure Submitted and Pending mean the record is being approved. Hold, Reassigned and NoResponse are the ones I'm unsure of.

Answer (score 5):

You are corrected that statuses **Submitted** and **Pending** mean the record is in the approval process but not yet approved.

**NoResponse:** If the approval step requires *unanimous* approval and one approver rejects the request, the value of this field for the *other* approvers changes to **NoResponse**. Likewise, If approval is based on the *first* response and an approver responds, the value of this field for the *other* approvers changes to **NoResponse**

**Reassigned:** Sent to a delegated approver in the approval process

Comment: This is great, thank you. Do you know what `Hold` means?